# Buddhist views on transgender issues

Tags: theravada, the-buddha, mahayana, lay-buddhism, dharmas

The Buddha or the scriptures do not state specifically if an individual being a transgender is right or wrong. So how would a Buddhist interpret this in a modern light and why?

Comment: Are you asking if it is right for them to continue to live instead of committing suicide? :D

Comment: No I'm asking whether being a transgender is wrong

Comment: @Hari Do you mean doing hormone therapy to change one's gender?

Comment: Probably duplicate of [Theravada perspective on transgender people](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/9302/254) -- see also [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/3991/254) for a hint at a Mahayana perspective.

Comment: When you ask whether it is wrong, are you asking "is it unethical?", or are you asking "is it factually discordant in that one identifies with something he is not"? Your question is still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who ''wants to end dukkha'', caring about the body is the first mistake, and trying to change the body is the second mistake. The third mistake is to base the actions, which let's recall are thinking, talking and moving the body, on the individual will (to talk like the secular humanists) or more generally on the various libidos, like the libido dominandi and libido sentiendi to talk like the full-on christians, which means on the sensations imagined, fantasised, expected, or even worse demanded , through some of the ''6 sense consciousnesses'', as the results of the actions based on the libido.
Overall, for anybody who want to stop being miserable, it is quite a blunder to even spend some energy on this.
For anybody who ''wants to end dukkha'', the actions are based on what gets the person closer to nirvana -- those are welcomed -- and what gets the person away from nirvana -- those are avoided -- which have nothing to do with pleasures, displeasures, comfort, lack of comfort, the will, the libido.

For the people who are satisfied with dukkha, it is quite natural to worry about the body, the senses and to base their actions on ''what they want'' or more generally on their desires (and then, even worse to build an identity on the pleasures and displeasures they have so far), since it is all they know ; which it turns out is a major source of misery, but they do not know that...

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question, your answer is misplaced